# JSON file cached when using flask

Tags: javascript, python, html, json, caching

I'm trying to do a visualization app in js + python. My app works like this:

1. in browser I have a textbox where I introduce an url
2. I send that url to python using Flask
3. in python I take that url, I process it, and I create a JSON file
4. in js I take that JSON file and I display the result in browser

The problem I encounter: I introduce the url in browser, click submit, and it shows me the result, this is ok. But the next time when I introduce another url, it shows me the same result as the previous, if I introduce another url, still the same result. So the JSON file is somehow cached somewhere. To resolve this I have to delete everytime the old JSON file and rename the new one in python code.

My question is, where should I put this JSON file to prevent caching? Or is there another way?

I have this hierarchy of files:

```
project
   |--- static
           |--- file.js
           |--- file.json
   |--- templates
           |--- file.html
   |--- file.py
```

This is what I am trying to do: http://whichlight.github.io/reddit-network-vis/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have one file `file.json` catering to multiple urls. This can only work if you are only dealing with one user at a time. I assume you're trying to cache the result, and for that you would need a different file for each url. A slightly better way would be to use an in-memory database like `redis` for that.

But if all you want to do is busting the cache, then instead of calling `file.json` in your ajax call, use `file.json?<randomstring>` like `file.json?t=<timestamp>`

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: url + "?" + (new Date()).getTime(),
  data: data,
  success: success
});
```

Comment: In py code I create that JSON file with a specific name, and in js I read the file. Will the timestamp in js work? I mean, I'll need to put the timestamp in py.

Comment: @AncaElena You have to put it in the JS/AJAX call, during execution. I've added a jquery example to the answer.

Comment: It worked!!! You saved me! For a newbie application, this is a perfect solution. Thank you very much!